# Avoiding script in Tumblr oembed API

Tags: php, api, tumblr, oembed

I need to work on oembed API of Tumblr. I completed Tumblr API but I need information how to disable script in Tumblr oembed api like in Twitter or Facebook. I tried to do as in Twitter API by adding omit_script=false

```
$tbdata = file_get_contents(
    'https://www.tumblr.com/oembed/1.0?url=https://breakup.tumblr.com/post/160221963841&omit_script=true'
);
```

Oembed is working but omit_script has no effect. Please let me know if the is any ways to work. The Tumblr api documentation does not describe anything about oembed except providing oembed endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

[oEmbed spec](http://oembed.com/) does not contain any option like `omit_script` to skip the script content in response. Only way to avoid it is to omit it from response.

I don't think even face book or twitter oEmbed api's have that support.